# How to store dynamic data in mongodb while using mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have a user schema as such:

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  
});
```

And the data stored in userSchema will be dynamic, **it is not pre-known to me**, not even the fields,(I am using the auth0 to get user data on signup) and I want to directly store it. I don't need any data sanitization for that. But the data might not always have same key value pairs.
Hence I basically want to store whatever comes in to the userSchema, but if I define it as empty and save some data like this:

```
const data = {
      name: 'vini',
      array: [{name:'vini'}, {name:'jaya'}, {name:'123'}],
      age: 20,
      gender: 'female',
      others: {key:value}
    };
const user = await User.create(data);
```

I rejects all the data and only generates the _id.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the strict option to false. In your case

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

}, { strict: false});
```

Here is the link in the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict